# Maven deploy hangs while downloading maven_metadata.xml if it exists already

Tags: xml, maven, repository

I have configured my project to be deployed to my own repository. When I run `mvn deploy` it looks like it's working but hangs at the stage for downloading the `maven_metadata.xml` file to after it's uploaded the jars.

```
INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ myproject ---
Uploading: scp://myrepodomain/.../myproject-0.06-2.jar
Uploaded: scp://myrepodomain/.../myproject-0.06-2.jar (39013 KB at 6234.1 KB/sec)
Uploading: scp://myrepodomain/.../myproject-0.06-2.pom
Uploaded: scp://myrepodomain/.../myproject-0.06-2.pom (8 KB at 21.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: scp://myrepodomain/.../maven-metadata.xml 
320/319 B
.....here is where it just hangs forever
```

If I delete the `maven-metadata.xml` file on the server, it works fine and just uploads a freshly generated one.

I should also mention that I am just using a simple HTTP server with SCP, I find the larger artifact systems to be way overkill for what I am doing. I can't figure out how to even debug this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: see bug https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEPLOY-177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be some obscure bug I was unable to find a reference to in Maven 3.0.5 (default in debian testing). Installing Maven 3.1.1 fixed this issue.

Comment: This has just started occurring for me using Maven 3.2.1.

Comment: On ubuntu I removed 3.0.5 with apt-get then manually installed 3.3.3  and the problem went away.

Comment: The apache ssh-Wagon is the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-429. You need version 2.9! This bug has been annoying for more than two years now! Major distributions have the bug e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with mvn 3.0.5

Comment: Remove or rename the maven folder

Answer (score 9):

With OS/X 10.9.3 and Maven  3.2.3, I had the same issue.

It seems to be the wagon plugin which is broken when downloading the files during the deploy.

I solved it by switching the wagon connector to ["Maven Wagon SSH External"](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ssh-external/index.html) in order to use the system ssh command.

Below my POM.xml modification :

```
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </extension>
```

switched to :

```
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </extension>
```

And replaced

```
    scp://myuser@myhost.com
```

By

```
    scpexe://myuser@myhost.com
```

into url tags :

```
    <repository>
        ...
        <url>scpexe://myuser@myhost.com</url>
        ...
    </repository>
```

Comment: Upgrading to a later version of wagon-ssh (in my case 2.9) solved the problem!

Comment: Same here, increasing the version to 2.10 fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

I have managed to fix this by swapping all references of scp to sftp in my pom.xml. The advantage of this solution is it does not require any additional configuration. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5605 for more information.

Comment: Perfect! Changing <distributionManagement><repository><url> protocol from scp to sftp solved my issue.

Comment: This is the best answer as it works with Maven 3.1.1 to even the latest Maven 3.5.0. `scp` and `scpexe` worked for maven 3.1.1 but stopped working for later versions of maven.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this. When I tried `wget` these `...maven_metadata.xml` URLs I received a 404 response.

My solution was to shorten the timeout for these servers (from 2 minutes default to 2 seconds).

First you have to find the ID of the repository for this URL. That is if you are stuck on downloading from artifactoryonline.org, search for this repository in your POMs:

```
$ find . -name 'pom*.xml' | xargs grep factoryonline
```

Go to the found POM and fetch the repository ID.
Then edit your `~/.m2/settings.xml` to something like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
            <server>
                    <id>Metamarkets-repository</id>
                    <configuration>
                            <httpConfiguration>
                                    <all>
                                            <connectionTimeout>2000</connectionTimeout>
                                            <readTimeout>2000</readTimeout>
                                    </all>
                            </httpConfiguration>
                    </configuration>
            </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

This will make the downloading give up after 2 seconds and let the build continue (assuming the `maven_metadata.xml` will be downloaded from somewhere else).